# Start over again for a question while appreciating given answers/efforts?

Tags: discussion, edits, asking-questions

I was asking a question which is pretty specific and I received answers and comments which already guided me into some direction. But I was not able to approve any of them as the 'solution'.

I am still willing — and I think it's necessary as I obviously still did not do well in asking it — to provide additional information which in minor parts would change the initial question (as it's very specific) and would in minor parts probably affect the 'correctness' of some answers.

I feel like when changing it now it ends up as some sort of 'mess' which I clearly want to avoid.

So if I edit the question I might get into trouble with some of the answers and comments and produce something which looks like a mess, but 'closing' it in favor of starting a fresh new question doesn't feel right either.

How do I get out of this trap?

Comment: You can write a self answer

Comment: but I don't have one yet, it's just about additionally clarifying the question while slightly changing it :-(

Comment: You don't have to close the question to start a new question. Just write a new question, mentioning the previous, and explaining how it's different so that it won't be closed as duplicate.

Comment: Maybe it is easier to provide guidance if you link us to the actual Q/A but in that case this whole question is better migrated to the site specific meta as the rules for what is acceptable or not depends per site. Be aware that linking to your question can cause the meta effect, leading to down/close votes if the question isn't that good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So if I edit the question I might get into trouble with some of the answers and comments and produce something which looks like a mess [...]

Editing your question to add *additional and relevant* information to your question to help solve the original problem is a good thing... what you shouldn't be doing is *changing* the question in any way that invalidates existing answers (don't worry too much about comments—they're transient and can just be removed).

> [...] but 'closing' it in favor of starting a fresh new question doesn't feel right either.

If you have a follow up question related to the same problem then there is absolutely nothing wrong with asking a new question. Place a link to the first question in your newer question to give context and clearly explain why this is indeed a separate question (you don't want it closed as a duplicate of the first)...

There's no pressing need to "close" (by which I assume you mean accept an answer) the first (or any) question at all. It's nice to accept an answer if it truly solved your problem or you think it will help solve the problem for others; but it isn't mandatory.

You can also add an answer yourself if you've come across a more complete solution on your own (you can reference and give credit to other's answers if they helped).